# A question on an inequality relating a function and its derivative

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)| \le k|f(x)|\;\forall x \in [0,1]$,($k>0$), then which of the following is always true?
>
> (A) $f(x)=0 \; \forall \; x \in \Bbb R$
> (B) $f(x)=0 \; \forall \; x \in [0,1]$
> (C) $f(x) \ne 0 \; \forall \; x \in [0,1]$
> (D) $f(1) = k$

This question appeared in a test I gave today (its obviously completed). I would love a hint on how to approach this question, and also some insight on how I should have thought about it from the beginning. Since mean value theorems were on syllabus (Lagrange's mean value theorem, Rolle's theorem) so I suspect their use is required, though I don't see how.

Thank you!

Comment: What's $k$? "Some positive constant"?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes! I forgot to type it in, it *was* given in the question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Hint: prove that $|f(x)|e^{-kx}$ is a decreasing function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @CanisLupus I'm just curious, but what is the motivation for this method of yours?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: $|f(x)|e^{-kx}\le |f(0)|e^{-k0}=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a multiple-choice question, we can settle on (B) just from process of elimination: (A) makes no sense because the domain of the function is $[0,1]$, and the constant function $0$ shows that (C) and (D) are false.

But this is a bit unsatisfying, so let's show that (B) is true: define
$$ g(x)=f(x)^2e^{-2kx}$$
for $0\leq x\leq 1$. Then $g(0)=0$, and 
$$ g^{\prime}(x)=2f(x)f^{\prime}(x)e^{-2k x}-2kf(x)^2e^{-2kx}=2e^{-2kx}(f^{\prime}(x)f(x)-kf(x)^2)$$
$$ \leq 2e^{-2kx}(|f^{\prime}(x)||f(x)|-kf(x)^2)\leq 2e^{-2kx}(k|f(x)|^2-kf(x)^2)=0 $$
Therefore $g$ is non-negative and non-increasing on $[0,1]$, so $0\leq g(x)\leq g(0)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. This implies that $f=0$ on $[0,1]$.